# Xcode 6 Cocoa Touch Framework Project Can't Find Public Headers

Tags: cocoa-touch, frameworks, ios8, xcode6

I'm having major issues trying to get Xcode to find any public header files in my Cocoa Touch framework project in Xcode 6. I have a very explicit folder structure within my framework project directory that goes something like this:

`APIKit -> DataModels -> User -> APIUser.h`

The "DataModels" directory is where I put all of my model objects and every object subtype will have its own sub-directory within DataModels (e.g. like APIUser above). Importing the above file in my APIKit.h header file looks like the following:

`#import <APIKit/DataModels/User/APIUser.h>`

However, for whatever reason, Xcode cannot find that dang file! Looking at my list of public headers from the project settings shows that the directory I outlined above is 100% correct. Does this make sense to anyone?

Update: Even `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` can't be found in my `APIKit.h` header file -- crazy!

Comment: Has anyone been experiencing this? I've been trying to solve this for days and it's driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to link the binaries in Xcode under build phases or are you saying xCode cannot find them in link section.

Comment: I'm saying Xcode cannot reconcile links to anything from my framework's public header file. Not `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` nor `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` nor any other `#import` I do which are known and found in any other context (e.g my Cocoa Touch classes) outside of it. Linking the UIKit and Foundation framework binaries to the project solves nothing. Moreover, there's no need to link any core framework like UIKit and Foundation to any project because, by default, LLVM takes care of auto-linking them during the linking phase.

Comment: and your saying you public headers folder path matches the path?

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to say there. When creating a new Cocoa Touch Framework project, the template auto-generates a public header file for you that you would then use in your other app projects when you include the framework project as part of a workspace. In that auto-generated framework public header file, nothing gets found or linked properly by Xcode. For you to see what I mean, create a new Cocoa Touch Framework project and see if you can Cmd+Click anything at all in that public header file -- `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` macro included (which also can't be found for me)

Comment: what I'm saying is that by default Xcode will not search user paths for the hears you create. We agree on that right?

Comment: Yes, by default Xcode does not search for `User Header Search Paths` which you can see under the project's Build Settings. Though I'm still not sure what you're trying to get at in all of that -- adding the `$(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PRODUCT_NAME)` where all of my class headers are located (framework public header file included) as a search path doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: ok well when you click on it do you include recursive to search each folder when adding your header in your project?

Comment: Including recursive search doesn't help Xcode find anything either.

Comment: And you have them as public header in your build phases?

Comment: also did you double check your build log for correct location? I've had that problem before. Is this the only one you're having problems with?